# Testing for Convexity for a function

Tags: convex-analysis

Please any one can help figure out if this funcion is concave or convex, any help is greatly appriciated. Any links on how to test fo convexity for such a function is also greatly appriciated. I tried to find the Hessian and I have some terms zero,so I am confused.

$f(p,q) = 1-p1*q1-p2*q2-p3*q3$

where all p and q are probabilities, i.e 0 $\le$ $p_i$ $\le$ 1 and 0 $\le$ $q_i$ $\le$ for i=1,2,3.

Thank you in advace.

Comment: You can add a constant to a function and it doesn't change convexity/concavity, so really you just want to know the convexity/concavity of $f(p,q) = - p \cdot q$.

Comment: Are the p-probabilities constrained to sum to unity? Are the q-probabilities so constrained also?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos yes, they sum to 1.

Comment: @user2566092, I am really not sure, I understand what you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A positive linear combination of concave/convex functions is again concave/convex.  For you, the base case is when you consider a single coordinate $f(p,q) = -p_iq_i$.  This function is concave for all $p_i,q_i$ in the interval $[0,1]$, so your overall function is concave.

Comment: and how, do you tell that −piqi is concave, sorry if it is a supid question

Comment: The Hessian is $H = \left({\begin{array}[cc] 00 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array}}\right)$ so $(x,y)H(x,y)^T = -2xy \leq 0$ if $x,y \geq 0$.

Comment: I probably should read some,more because for the H I, thought I get all zeros.

Comment: mybad,i get the H part of it, but what about the H transpose, what is that you doing? and please if not too much to ask, can you send me some good links? I find the det. and I got -1